# Logging in with Room Library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

So far in my android app I have been using Shared Preferences for storing local data. Now, I am working on replacing it with Room Persistance Library.

The thing that I am trying to accomplish here is quite simple, yet I am having some difficulty in achieving desired result.

Here is how my Logged In check works with Shared Preferences:

---

SplashScreenActivity:

```
if (splashViewModel.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, ProfileScreenActivity::class.java))
} else {
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginScreenActivity::class.java))
}
```

---

SplashViewModel:

```
fun isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return MainRepository.isUserLoggedIn()
    }
```

---

MainRepository:

```
fun isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return MySharedPreferences.isUserLoggedIn()
    }
```

---

MySharedPreferences:

```
fun isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return preferences.getBoolean(ID_USER_LOGGED_IN, false)
    }
```

As you can see - pretty simple and straightforward.

I was able to achieve similar thing with Room and LiveData, however, my implementation results in weird lag with SplashScreen and I think there might be something simpler when it comes to this.

Here is my Room & LiveData implementation:

---

SplashScreenActivity:

```
splashViewModel.isUserLoggedInRoom()

splashViewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, {
        if (it == true) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, ProfileScreenActivity::class.java))
        } else if (it == false) { 
                startActivity(Intent(this, LoginScreenActivity::class.java))
        }
})
```

---

SplashViewModel:

```
private val _isLoggedIn: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
val isLoggedIn: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoggedIn

    fun isUserLoggedInRoom() {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            val response = MainRepository.isUserLoggedInRoom()
            withContext(Main) {
                _isLoggedIn.value = response
            }
        }
    }
```

---

MainRepository:

```
fun isUserLoggedInRoom(): Boolean {
        return loginInfoDao.isLoggedIn()
    }
```

---

LoginInfoDao:

```
@Query("SELECT isLoggedIn FROM LoginInfo WHERE id=$LoginInfoID")
fun isLoggedIn(): Boolean
```

I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction here. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of lag? Like animation lag?

Comment: @GavinWright yes, exactly animation lag, which seems to happen when it starts switching to another activity

Comment: Have you tried building a release version of the app? You can never trust debug versions when it comes to animation lag issues.

Comment: @GavinWright To my surprise, this has actually worked. I have built release version and launched it on my phone and it works perfectly with no problems whatsoever. Just a side question - the way I handle this process in my code is correct?

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this was simple: Build Release version of the apk and run it instead of debug one.